# Dúvida com if dentro de um Partial View asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Na minha view eu tenho:

```
@if (Model.Count() > 0)
           {

             foreach (var item in Model)
             {
                 @Html.Partial("_FormularioPossibilidade", item)
             }


        }
```

Na Partial: @if (@Html.DisplayFor(c => Model.DESCRICAO03) != null)
o conteúdo e um texto,

```html
@model Generico.Dominio.TB_POSSIBILIDADE

@using (Html.BeginForm("GravarRegistro", "Possibilidade", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
            @Html.HiddenFor(c => Model.IDPOSSIBILIDADE)
            @Html.DisplayFor(c => Model.DESCRICAO01) | R$ @Html.DisplayFor(c => Model.VALOR01)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(c => Model.VALORAPOSTA1, new { placeholder = "0", @class = "form-control", type= "number", })
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
            @Html.DisplayFor(c => Model.DESCRICAO02) | R$ @Html.DisplayFor(c => Model.VALOR02)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(c => Model.VALORAPOSTA2, new { placeholder = "0", @class = "form-control", type = "number" })
        </div>

        @if (@Html.DisplayFor(c => Model.DESCRICAO03) != null)
        {
        <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
            @Html.DisplayFor(c => Model.DESCRICAO03) | R$ @Html.DisplayFor(c => Model.VALOR03)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(c => Model.VALORAPOSTA3, new { placeholder = "0", @class = "form-control", type = "number" })
        </div>
        }

    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @if(Model.DESCRICAO03!= string.Empty)
    {
    <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
        @Html.DisplayFor(c => Model.DESCRICAO03) | R$ @Html.DisplayFor(c => Model.VALOR03)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => Model.VALORAPOSTA3, new { placeholder = "0", @class = "form-control", type = "number" })
    </div>
    }
```